Is there are more concise way of writing this set cross product?
$   \overbrace{  \{a,b\} \times ....\times \{a,b\} }^{\textrm{ N-1 times }}\times \{c\}$
For $N=1$, I would like this to equal $\{(c)\}$.
For $N=2$, I would like this to equal $\{ (a,c),(b,c) \}$.
I realize that I can not write this as $ \{a,b\}^{ N-1}\times \{c\}$ because then I get the empty set for $N=1$.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Not really, $A^0$ is usually interpreted as a singleton set. (I’d consider it as ${\varnothing}$. Not sure if everyone would agree with that interpretation though.) So ${a, b}^{N - 1} \times {c}$ is (or at least in natural bijection with ${(c)}$.

For any set $A$, $A^0 = {f : \emptyset \to A} = {\emptyset}$.  So in your attempted answer, ${a, b}^0 \times {c} = {\emptyset} \times {c} = {(\emptyset, c)}$.  Is this close enough to what you want?

Thanks  Chris for the attempt, but the empty set there is a bit clunky.

In whatever you're writing, you could just use ${a,b}^{ N-1}\times {c}$ and clarify that this is to be interpreted as ${c}$ when $N=1$. It's fair to expect readers to make sense of minor issues like this.

Actually, $\{a,b\}^{N-1} \times \{c\}$ would work.
What is $S^0$ for some set? Well, $S^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of elements from $S$, so $S^0$ is the set of $0$-tuples of elements from $S$. A $0$-tuple is precisely a sequence of $0$ elements, of which there is exactly one, namely the empty tuple/sequence $()$.
Edit in response to comment from OP: So $\{a,b\}^0 \times \{c\}$ would be the set of all tuples consisting of $0$ elements from $\{a,b\}$ and then an element from $\{c\}$. But there is only one such tuple, namely $\{(c)\}$.
Multiple Cartesian products start getting a little clunky. Is $S \times (T \times U)$ the same as $(S \times T) \times U$ or $S \times T \times U$. They biject to each other in obvious ways, but they aren't the same. Likewise it's not exactly clear what the empty tuple is in the first place.

Do other people agree that this would work?  mathperson314 Could you please fill out your answer one more step.  What is cross product of an empty sequence with {c}?
